# Make Safari window smaller on Mac

Tags: macos, safari

Is there anyway to make the Safari window smaller by width on Mac? It will only let you make it about 500px in width before it stops. Basically I'm trying to test out some mobile web designs so I would like to have a smaller window in Safari.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can enter Responsive Design Mode to set a custom size and resolution of the viewport.

1. Enable the Develop menu from Settings → Advanced → Show Develop menu in menu bar
   [image: Safari Menu - Settings]
   [image: Settings - Advanced - Show Develop Menu]
2. Choose Develop → Enter Responsive Design Mode.
   [image: Enter Responsive Design Mode]
3. Select the desired mode and reload to apply.
   [image: View of Responsive Design Mode]
4. If a custom view size is required, drag the side handles.
   [image]